# Show that the sequence $A_n := \sqrt[n]{a} \ge 1$ is true for all positive integers $n$.(Induction?).

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, induction

This is my first question here so sorry if I'm messing up the format, still trying to get the hang of this.

Given is: $a\in\mathbf{R}$ with $a\ge1$ and $A_n=\sqrt[n]{a}$. 
and you can infer that $a = (A_n)^n$

I need to prove a bunch of things about the sequence $A_n = \sqrt[n]{a}$ ($n$ th root of $a$), but I'm still struggling with the first question still...  For the first part I need to show that $A_n≥1$ for all positive integers.

I think I need to show this by induction.
I've tested for $n = 1$.
For assumption: Let $n = k$, then $\sqrt[k]{a} \ge 1$ is true for at least one positive integer $k$. 
Then I think what I need to prove is that also $\sqrt[k+1]{a} \ge 1$.

I thought the best thing to do would be to start with my assumption and to get there: $\sqrt[k]{a}\ge 1$. Multiply by $\sqrt[k]{a}$.

$$(\sqrt[k]{a})\cdot\sqrt[k]{a} \ge 1\cdot\sqrt[k]{a}$$

$$\sqrt[k+1]{a} \ge \sqrt[k]{a}$$

Can I argue here that since $\sqrt[k]{a} \ge 1$ (Per assumption) then by transitivity is also $\sqrt[k+1]{a}\ge 1$?

That's where I got, and I'm not even sure if half the stuff I did is correct, or if I could even do it... I don't really understand the rules for $n$ th roots that well to be honest and we just recently started with induction, so I still lack practice with it, especially for inequalities.

Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you meant to say that if $A_n=\sqrt[n]{a}$ then $a=(A_n)^n$ rather than  $a=(A_n)^2$. Also $\sqrt[k]{a}\cdot\sqrt[k]{a}=\sqrt[k]{a^2}$ not $\sqrt[k+1]{a}$.

Comment: You're right, that's what I meant to say, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt[k]{a}$ is the same thing as $a^{\frac{1}{k}}$, so $\sqrt[k]{a} \cdot \sqrt[k]{a} = a^{\frac{1}{k}} \cdot a^{\frac{1}{k}} = a^{\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k}} = a^{\frac{2}{k}}$.

A hint on where to go would be to start at your assumptions and recall what $1^\frac{1}{x}$ equals. Also, you don't necessarily need induction to prove this. If you are studying induction right now, it's likely that a later part of the question is where induction becomes important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think you're right, I think I'm overcomplicating it by using Induction... How do you think I should get about proving this?? Perhaps by Contradiction??

Comment: This should be a direct proof. You know that $a>1$ and want to prove $A_n>1$. What step(s) can you take to turn one inequality into the other?